# Preventing Overlaps of Values

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have the following array

```
array (size=5)
0 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 1
1 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 14
2 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 23
3 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 24
4 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 27
```

I want to prevent overlapping, I means each one should be at least different by value/interval of 5, and at the same time I don't want the final margin max than 30.

and the margins should only plus/minus around their current values, like the final output can  be like below

```
array (size=5)
0 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 1
1 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 14
2 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 19
3 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 24
4 => 
array (size=1)
  'margin' => 29
```

So far, I have tried the following code to detect the overlaps

```
while(list($i, $v) = each($data)) {

    if(!empty($data[$i+1]["margin"])){

        if(($data[$i+1]["margin"]-$v["margin"])<5)
            echo "Overlapping index : ".($i+1).PHP_EOL;

        }
}
```

but I am having difficulty in doing some algorithm to remove the overlaps in place.

> P.S. all the data in array is sorted (margin wise).

Can anybody help me regarding? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to recurs through your array:

```
function f($i)
{
   global $n, $margins;
   // check if index is not out of range 
   if ($i < $n)
   {
        // skip first margin in array   
        if ($i>0)
        {
            // stop if 30 is reached
            if ($margins[$i]['margin'] <= 30)
            {
                // ajust margin if smaller than 5
                if (($margins[$i]['margin'] - $margins[$i-1]['margin']) < 5)
                    $margins[$i]['margin'] = $margins[$i-1]['margin'] + 5;
                // recurs to the next item in the array
                f($i+1);
            }
            else
                unset($margins[$i]);
        }
        else
            f($i+1);
   }
}

// initialize $margin
$margins = array(
            array('margin'=>3),
            array('margin'=>7),
            array('margin'=>15),
            array('margin'=>25),
            array('margin'=>30)
          );    

var_dump($margins); echo "</br>";     

// initialize $n 
$n = count($margins);

// Call recursive function  
f(1);

var_dump($margins); echo "</br>";
```

This is because the size of your margins array is small, larger array would use  memory resources.